# Writing to file in C

Tags: c

I wanted to make a program that asks for any number that isn't bigger than 1337 and then starting from that number(1334 for example) prints the following lines to text file.

- <1334133413341334
- <1335133513351335
- <1336133613361336
- <1337133713371337

This is what I've got so far...
it seems to write only the last line which is <1337133713371337

---

```
include <stdio.h>
include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   //char c[1000];
   int c, e = 1337;
   FILE *fptr;
   fptr=fopen("num_gen.txt","w");
   if(fptr==NULL){
      printf("Error!");
      exit(1);
   }

   printf("Enter a number:\n");
   scanf("%d",&c);
   for (c = 0; c != e; c++)
   {
      printf("<%d%d%d%d\n", c, c, c, c);
   }

   fprintf(fptr,"<%d%d%d%d\n", c, c, c, c);
   fclose(fptr);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: You might like to learn how to use a debugger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at where `fptr` is used. You only ever write to it once at the end.

```
   fprintf(fptr,"<%d%d%d%d\n", c, c, c, c);
```

All the prints in the loop are using `printf` which goes to stdout.

```
   for (c = 0; c != e; c++)
   {
      printf("<%d%d%d%d\n", c, c, c, c);
   }
```

Comment: ok so i changed printf("<%d%d%d%d\n", c, c, c, c); to fprintf(fptr, "<%d%d%d%d\n", c, c, c, c); but it now prints everything from 0 to 1336, doesnt matter what input

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer Schwern, i just had to modify my for cycle a little bit. Looks something like this:

---

```
for (c; c != e; c++)
   {
      fprintf(fptr, "<%d%d%d%d\n", c, c, c, c);
   }
```

Comment: Consider using `c < e`.   Otherwise consider what would be the output if the user entered `1338`.

Comment: Do not say "Thanks" in answers.

Answer (score 0):

You are printing to screen and then to the file. That is the reason your are only seeing the last line in the file.

Change the inner loop printf to fprintf. Also the loop should be;-

```
for (int i = c; i != e; i++)
 {
  fprintf(fptr, "<%d%d%d%d\n", i, i, i, i);
 }
```